# Jsp auto forwarding

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting

How I can to make auto forwarding from any dir to .jsp page with params, such as:

```
http://site.net/foo/ -> http://site.net/show.jsp?p=foo
http://site.net/foo2/ -> http://site.net/show.jsp?p=foo2
http://site.net/foo3/ -> http://site.net/show.jsp?p=foo3
http://site.net/foo4/ -> http://site.net/show.jsp?p=foo4
```

Comment: how about using java Filter or RewriteFilter (http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UrlRewriterFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to achieve this (MVC independent, since I don't know how you're implementing your webapp).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your app server behind Apache you can achieve this with mod_rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html